# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream on myStore.CreateFile(fileName) method

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I don't know why I'm facing that error !
Here is my code snippet :

```
public void SaveImageTo(string fileName="ABC.jpg") 
    {
        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName);
        qrImage.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, qrImage.PixelWidth, qrImage.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        myFileStream.Close();

        // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
        myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        //byte[] buffer = ToByteArray(qrImage);
        library.SavePicture(fileName, myFileStream);
    }
```

It gives me "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream", Here qrImage is a global writablebitmap. need help !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's the *actual* value of `fileName` when it fails? "ABC.jpg" is only the default value of the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it !
Disconnecting USB made it ok!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add for further information. This was happening as you were connected to Zune hence under Sync. And on removing USB, sync is completed. Hence you can now access media library. Thus error is resolved